# Installing netCDF4 for Python fails, how to fix?

Tags: python, netcdf

I have tried installing netCDF4 for Windows ([from here](http://netcdf4-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/netCDF4-module.html)) and I still cannot import netCDF4 modules.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
>>> import netCDF4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named netCDF4
```

There are the modules in the site-packages directory:

```
James@desktop /cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/site-packages
$ ls net*
netcdf.dll         netCDF4_utils.pyo             netcdftime.pyc
netCDF4.pyd        netCDF4-1.0.4-py2.7.egg-info  netcdftime.pyo
netCDF4_utils.py   netCDF4-1.0.5-py2.7.egg-info
netCDF4_utils.pyc  netcdftime.py
```

Are there further steps I need to complete after running the installer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I presume from the site-packages directory name that it's Cygwin Python.

You need to ensure that the site-packages directory is on the Python module search path. I forget just how this is done--I have notes on how I did it, but they're at work and I'm at home--but there are instructions for it on the Python site. For Cygwin Python you want the Unix instructions. Something to do with adding a file called site.pth somewhere under /usr??

Comment: Further to my answer above, when I built netCDF4-Python I installed it with prefix /usr/local (AKA C:\Cygwin\usr\local). This caused the files to be placed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages. To add this directory to the Python search path, I created a file with the path /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/local_packages.pth, with a single line consisting of/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages